# Как правильно: "поверие или поверье"?

Tags: орфография

Меня почему-то всегда тянет написать "поверИе", но ворд всегда подчеркивает и предлагает вариант "поверье". А как правильно? Или, может, возможны оба варианта?
Спасибо

Comment: Отправила вопрос на сайт "Грамота.ру", причем он касается не только варианта поверие/поверье, но и всех подобных слов в части их обозначения в словарях. Будем ждать ответа, а Вам спасибо за интересный вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Сперва правило:

> Написание -ние (-ание, -ение) или -нье (-анье, -енье) в суффиксах 
> отглагольных существительных связано или со смысловым различием, или со 
> стилистической дифференциацией.
> 1)      В смысловом отношении различаются: *варение, печение, соление* 
> [процесс, то же, что «варка», «выпечка», «засол» – *варенье, печенье, 
> соленье* (результат процесса, продукт); *воскресение* (действие по 
> глаголу воскресить) – *воскресенье* (день недели); *жалование* 
> (пожалование, присуждение) — *жалованье* (денежное вознаграждение за 
> работу)] и т.п.
>
> 2)      Слова книжные пишутся с суффиксом -ние, слова обиходные — с 
> суффиксом -нье, например:
> а)      *воспитание, достижение, замедление, искоренение, оформление, 
> процветание, разграничение, склонение, усыновление, формирование, 
> членение, явление;
>
> б)      барахтанье, беганье, воркованье, дерганье, кваканье, кряхтенье, 
> тявканье, фырканье, харканье, хихиканье, чавканье, чириканье, шиканье, 
> щелканье.*

Так как под пункт "1" наш пример не подходит, придется разобраться 
книжное это слово или нет. А вот тут получается интересная вещь. Поверье
 - это буквально, несовсем вера, "околоверие". Это "около" дает нам 
возможность считать слово обыденным и писать через "ь", что и 
рекомендуют словари. Однако, если рассматривать их как нечто серьезное, 
то допустимо использование "и".

В общем, если перед нами "бабушкины сказки", то пишем "поверье", а если "предками данная, мудрость народная" - через "и".

Comment: Марк Из, у Вас авторская орфография? Тогда лучше говорить "пишу", а не "пишем".

Comment: @София, ничуть не авторская, а согласно правилам. Другое дело, что в силу семантики, "поверье" подразумевает под собой как раз "бабушкины сказки", суеверия, что предполагает как раз обиходное значение с "ь". Однако, когда в **исключительных** случаях предлагают отнестись к поверьям серьёзно, **возможно** появление "и". Причём у вполне серьёзных мастеров слова вроде Брюсова, Пришвина, Станиславского.

> Поверие — младшая сестра веры. «Стада богов», оттесненные христианством.

М. М. Пришвин.

Comment: Вот у Зощенко: "Это не какое-нибудь там темное поверие или, может быть, старинный обычай..." (1921). По-моему, это просто старая орфография, когда позволялось использовать обе формы, сравнить: "Рассуждали о том, что мусульманское поверье..." (М. Лермонтов). А сейчас разрешена только одна форма, остается только выяснить, с какого времени.

Comment: Видимо совсем недавно. Посмотрел, последнее вхождение слова в базу Нацкорпуса двухтысячные годы, причём употребляют его даже доктора филологических наук, академики РАН.

> *Повер**и**я* германских и кельтских народов постепенно усваивают христианскую оболочку и просачиваются в западную агиографию, определяя собой своеобразие ее окраски.

С. С. Аверинцев. "Судьбы европейской культурной традиции в эпоху перехода от античности к Средневековью".

Comment: У меня есть орфоэпический словарь Аванесова за 1987 год, там указана одна форма -  "поверье".

Comment: А вот еще интересная пара: счастье/ счастие. У Лермонтова, у Толстого используется слово "счастие" (книжная форма), а сейчас - только "счастье" (разговорная форма стала единственно разрешенной).

Comment: @София, отсутствие слова в словаре, не означает, что его нет. Сей факт означает лишь то, что слово редко употребляют. Попыток сделать словарь **всех** слов русского языка насколько знаю не было со времён Даля.

Comment: Мне  кажется,  что  оба  написания  возможны  и  равноправны.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: поверЬе. Такое написание зафиксировано в орфографическом словаре Российской академии наук, под редакцией Лопатина. Такое написание встречается и в других как орфографических, так и толковых словарях. Но в одном словаре синонимов  размещенным на Академике, встречаются оба варианта. Однако следует считать правильным тот вариант, который зафиксирован в орфографическом словаре.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: поверье.

Две формы могут различаться ПО СТИЛЮ ИЛИ ПО СМЫСЛУ. Формы на ИЕ часто являются общеупотребительными и стилистически нейтральными, а формы на ЬЕ характерны для разговорной и поэтической речи, например: молчание (нейтр.) и молчанье (разг.)

В то же время существование двух стилистических форм определяется по словарю, например: спасение и спасенье. Слово "поверие" не отмечено ни в старых, ни в современных словарях, например: "Во всяком подворье свое поверье".В.И. Даль. Пословицы русского народа.

Comment: Интересное суждение по поводу словаря, в котором не указана та форма слова ("поверие"), которую я собираюсь написать, но которая, по моему мнению, там должна быть, вот я ее и пишу. Так можно объяснить ошибку в любом слове, например, "танцовать", "итти". Такая орфография встречалась до 1956 года.

Comment: @София, слова "танцовать" и "итти" противоречит правилам русского языка, а слово "поверие" - нет. Так что не стоит перегибать палку.

 В Нацкорпусе примерно одинаковое количество вхождений "поверия" как до, так и после 1956 года. И тогда и после оно было сккорее исключением, чем правилом. Тот же Пришвин, гораздо чаще писал "поверье", но "поверие" тоже бывало.